# Extracting value using common_schema not working for nested JSON

Tags: mysql, json, common-schema

I have a DB field called `data` of type is *MEDIUMTEXT*, which stores values in JSON format. I'm using `extract_json_value` method from `common_schema`.

When JSON is not nested, it works fine. For example, when `applications_data` table's `data` field is

```
{
  "key": "value"
}
```

This query works fine:

```
SELECT data into @json from applications_data;
SELECT common_schema.extract_json_value(@json, 'key') as result;
```

and gives result: `key`

However, when the data field is a nested JSON, it fails. For example, JSON is:

```
{
  "key": {
    "overview": "sample"
  }
}
```

Using the same query as above and result is empty, not NULL:

[image]

Comment: Can you add an example of the nested JSON, the query that you are trying to execute and the expected result?.

Comment: @wchiquito edited the question. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember:

> [extract_json_value](http://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/extract_json_value.html)
>
> ...
>
> This function internally relies on [json_to_xml()](http://shlomi-noach.github.io/common_schema/json_to_xml.html): it first
>   converts the JSON data to XML, then uses [ExtractValue](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) to apply
>   XPath.
>
> ...

and

> [ExtractValue(xml_frag, xpath_expr)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue)
>
> ...
>
> If no matching text node is found for the expression (including the
>   implicit **/text()**)—for whatever reason, as long as ***xpath_expr*** is valid, and ***xml_frag*** consists of elements which are properly nested and closed—an empty string is returned. No distinction is made between a match on an empty element and no match at all. This is by design.
>
> If you need to determine whether no matching element was found in
>   ***xml_frag*** or such an element was found but contained no child text
>   nodes, you should test the result of an expression that uses the XPath
>   **count()** function.
>
> ...

Test:

```sql
mysql> SET @`json` := '
    '> {
    '>   "key": {
    '>     "overview": "sample"
    '>   }
    '> }
    '> ';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT 
    ->   common_schema.extract_json_value(@`json`, 'key') AS result0,
    ->   common_schema.extract_json_value(@`json`, count('key')) AS result1,
    ->   common_schema.extract_json_value(@`json`, 'key/overview') AS result2,
    ->   common_schema.extract_json_value(@`json`, count('key/overview')) AS result3;
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| result0 | result1 | result2 | result3 |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|         | 1       | sample  | 1       |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```